# Square root of the product of a diagonal and symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

If I have a diagonal matrix $D$ and a positive-definite symmetric matrix $C$, is there a formula for the square root of the product, $(DC)^{1/2}$? Also, $DC \neq CD$.

What I have so far is
\begin{align}
(DC)^{1/2} &= D^{1/2}(D^{1/2} C D^{1/2})^{1/2}D^{-1/2}
\end{align}
Can the middle term be broken down any further? I am trying to use $C^{1/2}$ or $C^{-1/2}$ somehow but am unable to.

Edit: I am trying to see if $D^{1/2}CD^{1/2}$ can be written as the sum of a diagonal matrix with an outer product, $(D+cc^T)^{1/2}$, if that would make things simpler. If the diagonal is the same i.e. the identity matrix, I could calculate $(I+cc^T)^{1/2}$ but having different values in the diagonal makes it more difficult.

I could calculate $(D+cc^T)^{1/2}$ with a Cholesky rank-one update, but I'm looking for a non-iterative formula.

In order to find this, I would need to find an idempotent matrix of the form $(D-A)$ where $A^2=A$. $(I-A)$ is idempotent [but I think it is impossible when it is not the identity matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3660011/idempotent-matrix-of-the-form-d-a).

Comment: Assuming you are calling $C^{1/2}$ the "principal square root" of $C$, note that $DC$ is not symmetric if $D$ has distinct entries. Even if $D$ has identical entries, $DC$ may not be positive definite either. I'd say it seems unlikely that there is a general formula. Of course, if $D$ has identical positive entries, then the square root is the one you'd imagine.

Comment: Yes, $D$ will not have identical values, so you're right that $DC$ won't be symmetric. If $DC$ does not commute, could there be any matrix $B$ such that $BD^{1/2}=D^{1/2}B$? If so, let C=BDB so that $(D^{1/2}CD^{1/2})^{1/2} = (D^{1/2}BDBD^{1/2})^{1/2} = (D^{1/2}BD^{1/2}D^{1/2}BD^{1/2})^{1/2}=D^{1/2}BD^{1/2}$

Comment: Take $B$ as any diagonal matrix with identical entries then?

Comment: But if $B$ is diagonal, $BD^{1/2}$ would also be diagonal and that wouldn't work if $C$ is not assumed to be diagonal.