# Idempotent matrix of the form $(D-A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, idempotents

Does there exist an idempotent matrix of the form $P=(D-A)$ where $P^2 = P$ if $A$ is idempotent? $D$ is a diagonal matrix with positive distinct entries. For the trivial case when $D$ is the identity matrix,
\begin{align}
(I - \frac{aa^T}{a^Ta})(I - \frac{aa^T}{a^Ta}) &= I - 2\frac{aa^T}{a^Ta}+\frac{(a^Ta)aa^T}{(a^Ta)^2}\\
&= I - \frac{aa^T}{a^Ta}
\end{align}
I am trying to figure this out because I have to take the square root of a matrix of a diagonal matrix plus a positive definite symmetric matrix. If I can figure out some $P$, I should be able to find a way.

Comment: In general, there is no easy way to get the square root of a diagonal matrix plus a positive semidefinite matrix

Comment: If $D$ is diagonal with entries equal to $0,1,2$, then it's easy to construct such an $A$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a positive definite $D$, $P$ only exist if $D=I$ since $I$ is the only diagonal matrix that commutes with an idempotent matrix $A$.

The sum of a diagonal matrix plus a positive definite matrix is positive definite. Thus, you can use Cholesky decomposition. If the matrix is sparse, the Incomplete Cholesky decomposition is a more efficient alternative.

Comment: Thanks for that! With a Cholesky rank-one downdate using $LL^T=A$, I can obtain some $\tilde{L}$ where $\tilde{L}\tilde{L}^T=\tilde{A}=D-A$. Do you think it's possible to obtain general formula for a symmetric matrix $C^{1/2}$ where $C^{1/2}C^{1/2}=D-A$? Or Cholesky is best that can be done?

Comment: It is that $A$ still idempotent? What is the dimension of the matrix that you want to decompose? I think that if your matrix is not huge, then the best way is to do Cholesky decomposition directly. The $\verb|?potrf|$ subroutine from LAPACK or MKL is extremely efficient and easy to implement. If you can do it directly is better because with rank-one downdate you need to check if $D-A$ is PD.

Comment: I don't think that exists a general formula for $C^{1/2}$. First note that $C^{1/2}$ is symmetric iff $A$ is symmetric. Then, if $D=k\,I$ for $k \geq 1$, then $D-A=kI-U\Lambda U'=U(kI-\Lambda)U'$, so $C^{1/2}=U(kI-\Lambda)^{1/2}U'$. But if $D$ has distinct diagonal entries, I think no general formula exists.

Comment: $A$ is symmetric. It can be thought of, in my case, as an outer product $aa^T$. I guess eigendecomposition is the closest one can get to a 'formula' for $C^{1/2}$. There are some bounds on the eigenvalues for a rank-one up/down-date and [the eigenvectors can also be found](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunch%E2%80%93Nielsen%E2%80%93Sorensen_formula)

Comment: $A$ can still be idempotent if it is $aa^T/a^Ta$. It's not a question of computation--the matrix is small. I just was curious if there existed a general formula of the square root for a diagonal matrix with distinct entries with a rank-one perturbation.